# What is the negative login time in the "last" command?

Tags: 20.04, login, systemd-logind

[image]

When I use the `last` command, the log time is minus. I don't know what it means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Last column shows how long the user has logged in basically a difference between login and logout time, negative time may be listed when the clocks were not in sync ie date/time was incorrect when the time was logged.